# Select which member function to call at compile time

Tags: c++

I have a templated class on some object `T`. `T` defines two member functions `bar` and `foo`

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
   void f() {
       t_.bar();
       t_.foo();
   }
private:
T t_;
};
```

Now I would like be able to tell `A` (ideally at compile time), to call either `foo` or `bar`, but not both. So the idea is to tell A at construction time which member function of `T` to call.

The solution I have currently in place is to pass a callable `void callMember(const T& t) { return t.foo(); }` in `A`'s constructor to at runtime call the right member, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution?

Comment: You can specialise your template so the function is selected automagically by the compiler

Comment: There is no compile-time solution that doesn't involve making each option a distinct type. If that's a problem for you, you need to stick to runtime decisions.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `bool` template parameter to `A` that tells it which member function of `T` to call, and then use a `constexpr if` on that parameter in the body of `f`:

```
template<class T, bool Choice>
class A {
public:
   void f() {
    if constexpr(Choice)  // doesn't strictly have to be constexpr
                          // if T defines both bar and foo
       t_.bar();
    else
       t_.foo();
   }
private:
T t_;
};
```

Now for some type like:

```
struct S {
    void bar() { std::cout << "bar"; }
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo"; }
};
```

you can do:

```
A<S, true> a;
a.f();        // calls S::bar

A<S, false> b;
b.f();        // calls S::foo
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hc83Kh1s5).

Answer (score 0):

I assume its Ok to have instantiations of  `A` be of different type depending on which method is called. If that is the case I suggest to choose between two types rather than two methods.

Say `X` is the type with the two methods, then you can do this:

```
struct X { 
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
};

struct Xfoo {
    X x;
    void foobar() { x.foo(); }
};

struct Xbar {
    X x;
    void foobar() { x.bar(); }
};
```

Now the template is:

```
template<class T>
class A {
   public:
   void f() {
       t_.foobar();
   }
   private:
   T t_;
};
```

And you either instantiate `A<Xfoo>` or `A<Xbar>` rather than `A<X>`.

I suppose you have more than just one type `X`, then `Xfoo` and `Xbar` can be parametrized on the type to be wrapped.